# How can I get vestal_versions to store the user who changed the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, vestal-versions

I'm using `vestal_versions` 1.0.2 and `rails` 2.3.8

I'm trying to associate a user with changes made to models as shown in the the documentation:

```
@user.update_attributes(:last_name => "Jobs", :updated_by => "Tyler")
@user.versions.last.user # => "Tyler"
```

Documentation: http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions

After calling `@user.save` the user "Tyler" is NOT saved in `versions` table used by vestal_versions.

Has anybody seen this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this one out? I'm curious too!

Comment: Posted my workaround. Hope this bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with mass assignment and the `updated_by` parameter.

My workaround looks like this:

```
@my_model.updated_by = current_user
@my_model.save
```

I added the assignment before every `save` or `update_attributes` call in the controllers.